# How to Query the "Assigned To" field form Proces Instance

Tags: apex, approval-process

I want to query the "Assigned To" field from Proces Instance.
How can i get the "Assigned To" field  from Approval Process.

Actually I have to list out all Approval process which is assigned to Current login user.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Object **ProcessInstanceStep** and it has a field **ActorId**.

> **ActorId:** ID of the user who is currently assigned to this approval
>   step.

So you can query this object to list out all Approval process which is assigned to Current login user.

For more information click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processinstancestep.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. But When User "A" submit the record for Approval, then It'll be assigned to User "B".  That time Actor ID is returning id of user  "A".